# Mutt authentication fails because username string is malformed

Tags: email, authentication, mutt

I'm trying to set up mutt to work with our internal email server. Our user names have the form

```
user@domain.lan
```

But when mutt tries to authenticate, it appends the mail server's url to the username string:

```
user@domain.lan@mail.domain.lan
```

Authentication fails, and I'm assuming this is the reason why.

Here's my full muttrc:

```
set imap_user = "user@domain.lan"
set folder = "imaps://mail.domain.lan:993/"
set spoolfile = +INBOX
set imap_check_subscribed
set postponed = +Drafts
set record = +Sent
set header_cache = "~/.cache/mutt"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificate"
unset imap_passive
set imap_keepalive = 300
set mail_check = 120
```

We don't have the this problem with Thunderbird, using the same configuration. Is there a wat force mutt not to append the servers url?

Comment: How are you constructing `imap_user`? Is it hardcoded or are you doing variable interpolation that might not be doing what you expect?

Comment: It's hard coded. `imap_user = user@domain.lan`

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using URL syntax notation for the IMAP folder as explained [in the manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#url-syntax).

This should work for the mailbox name:

```
imaps://user@domain.lan:password@mail.domain.lan
```

From the manual:

> This has the advantage that multiple IMAP, POP3 or SMTP servers may be
>   specified (which isn't possible using, for example, $imap_user). The
>   username may contain the “@” symbol being used by many mail systems as
>   part of the login name.

Comment: I tried setting the folder directive as you suggest, but it didn't change anything. It still attempts to authenticate for `user@domain.lan@mail.domain.lan`